# Remove spaces from all column names in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am new to pySpark. I have received a csv file which has around 1000 columns. I am using databricks. Most of these columns have spaces in between eg "Total Revenue" ,"Total Age" etc. I need to updates all the column names with space with underscore'_'.

I have tried this

```
foreach(DataColumn c in cloned.Columns)
    c.ColumnName = String.Join("_", c.ColumnName.Split());
```

but it didn't work in Pyspark on databricks.

Answer (score 21):

I would use `select` in conjunction with a `list` comprehension:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

renamed_df = df.select([F.col(col).alias(col.replace(' ', '_')) for col in df.columns])
```

Comment: Excellent response (+1). If you want to replace only the leading an trailing spaces you can do: `renamed_df = df.select([F.col(col).alias(col.strip()) for col in df.columns])`

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to remove the spaces from the column names:
1. Use a schema while importing the data to spark data frame:
for example:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType
Schema1 = StructType([StructField('field1', IntegerType(), True),
                     StructField('field2', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('field3', IntegerType(), True)])
df = spark.read.csv('/path/to/your/file.csv', header=True, schema=Schema1)
```

2. If you have already got the data imported into a dataframe, use dataframe.withColumnRenamed function to change the name of the column:

   df=df.withColumnRenamed("field name","fieldName")

Comment: Interesting.. when I did `df =df.withColumnRenamed("field name", "fieldname")` , it did not work for me on databricks. This was the reason I was looking to replace "field name" with "field_name".

Answer (score 2):

```
NewColumns=(column.replace(' ', 'any special character') for column in df.columns)
df = df.toDF(*NewColumns)
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works, Ive been using it since a very long time.
you just have to import re.

```
import re 
schema1 = [re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9,]", "", i) for i in df1.columns] 
df2 = df1.toDF(*schema1)
```

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, it is actually an overreach.
`[i.replace("_", "") for i in df.columns]`
will do the work too, without the need of importing `re`

Answer (score 0):

you can use strip function which replace leading and trail spaces in columns. you may use

```
df = df.select([F.col(c).alias(c.strip()) for c in df.columns])
```

instead of strip, you may also use lstrip or rstrip functions as well in python.