# Pyspark concat column based on other columns values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working with pyspark below is my dataframe

```
col_list   | col_1| col_2 |...|col_n
col_1,col2 | x    | y     |...|n
col_2,col_n| a    | b     |...|z
```

I want concat columns which are present in my col_list column values

Expected DF:

```
col_list   | col_1| col_2 |...|col_n | concat_cols
col_1,col2 | x    | y     |...|n     | [col_1:x,col_2:y]
col_2,col_n| a    | b     |...|z     | [col_2:b,col_n:z]
```

Trying with below approaches:

1. Creating udf to pass col_list and create expression to create array col like array(df['col_1'],df['col_2']) , but this will create column with string , not sure how to execute expression
2. Using create map passing col_list in loop and create column, need to check on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some map methods:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'col_map', 
    F.map_from_arrays(
        F.array([F.lit(c) for c in df.columns[1:]]), 
        F.array(df.columns[1:])
    )
).withColumn(
    'concat_cols', 
    F.expr("""
        map_from_arrays(
            split(col_list, ','), 
            transform(split(col_list, ','), x -> col_map[x])
        )
    """)
).drop('col_map')

df2.show(truncate=False)
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+------------------------+
|col_list   |col_1|col_2|col_n|concat_cols             |
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+------------------------+
|col_1,col_2|x    |y    |n    |[col_1 -> x, col_2 -> y]|
|col_2,col_n|a    |b    |z    |[col_2 -> b, col_n -> z]|
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+------------------------+
```

If you prefer a string representation rather than a map type column, you can do

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'col_map', 
    F.map_from_arrays(
        F.array([F.lit(c) for c in df.columns[1:]]), 
        F.array(df.columns[1:])
    )
).withColumn(
    'concat_cols', 
    F.expr("""
        concat_ws(',', 
            transform(split(col_list, ','), x -> concat_ws(':', x, col_map[x]))
        )
    """)
).drop('col_map')

df2.show(truncate=False)
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+---------------+
|col_list   |col_1|col_2|col_n|concat_cols    |
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+---------------+
|col_1,col_2|x    |y    |n    |col_1:x,col_2:y|
|col_2,col_n|a    |b    |z    |col_2:b,col_n:z|
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+---------------+
```

Comment: i am getting [col_1 -> x, col_2 -> ] in concat_cols

Comment: did you have spaces in your column names? that may cause issues

Comment: there are chances, happening to few  columns

Comment: Then you need to make sure to remove spaces. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57318519/remove-spaces-from-all-column-names-in-pyspark

Comment: verified, dont have any spaces in column names, in col_map i can see value as col_2 -> y but in final concat_col it is coming as col_2 ->

Comment: getting spaces for some records in col_lis causing issue, fixed by chaining col_map[x] to  col_map[trim(x)]